# How to get category by id joomla 3?

Tags: joomla3.0

In every category page I need to make a block that shows related categories. To add this related categories in admin panel I've already created a field for that. Now, in j_categories table, I have column 'params' with something like this - {"show_title":"1","category_layout":"","image":"",**"related":["12","23"]**,"image_alt":"","show_related_categories":"1"}

So I have the ids of related categories.

How can I get titles of these categories and put these titles to the category page?

Sorry for my English. Thank you in advance.